# Entity Framework SQLQuery does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET Entity Framework and I am trying to do an SQLQuery to do an INNER JOIN and get only certain columns, I dont want all the columns, just a few. But when I run this:

```
db.Data.SqlQuery(
    @"SELECT p.interestedID as id, s.dateSlot, s.timeSlot, 
             s.startTime, s.dateCreated, s.email, p.email 
      FROM Sales s 
      INNER JOIN Interested p 
            ON s.email = p.email 
      ORDER BY s.dateSlot, s.timeSlot"
).ToList()
```

I get this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'Project.Models.Sales'. A member of the type, 'firstname', does not
>   have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Is this the best way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish? And if what is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: can you use a linq query or lambda expression instead?

Comment: Ummmm, interesting, can you provide an example @JamieD77

Comment: You could create a new model class that contained only the properties your query is requesting.  (ie, make your model match your query).

Comment: `var q = (from p in db.Interested 
  join s in db.Sales on p.email equals s.email 
  select new {
   id = p.interestedID, 
   dateSlot = s.dateSlot, 
   timeSlot = s.timeSlot, 
   startTime = s.startTime, 
   dateCreated = s.dateCreated, 
   email = s.email, 
   email = p.email }).ToList();`  this will give you an anonymous object with the properties you need.. if you have a model that matches you can use `select new MyModel {} instead`

Comment: Sounds like the model you try to fill has required field that you don't supply in query